# CGpoint Array write into a text file

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsarraycontroller

I have an array like this: `CGPoint array[1000]` (I add location of touches into this array). The problem is that I want to save this array into a text file in the document directory and also retrieve it. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks All

Comment: Your question is incorrectly being formatted as code. Can you fix it?

Comment: my problem is can we store a Cgpointsarray into text file..??

Comment: Yes I understood your question (although you could make it clearer). I was making a point about your entire question being incorrectly formatted as _code_.

Comment: ok i take a array in .h file like CGPoint array[1000] and in touch moved  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self] and  array[count]=location; so i got all the points of touch..but problem is how can i save this array into text file....and if it is not possible so there have other option to save touch points and retrieve it...i hope this will help u...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a plain C array, I would recommend that you use an `NSArray` to store your collection of CGPoints. Since `NSArray` conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol, you can serialize and deserialize it from a file.

You should read up on [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).

**EDIT** Here's an example:

```
// Create an NSMutableArray
NSMutableArray *points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Add a point to the array
// Read up on NSValue objects to understand why you simply cannot add a C 
// struct like CGPoint to the array
[points addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&point1 objCType:@encode(CGPoint)]];

// archive the array -- this will store the array in a file
BOOL result = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:points toFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"Archival result: %d", result);

// unarchive the array -- this will retrieve your array from the file
NSMutableArray *points2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
```

Comment: I have added the code sample, but you really _should_ go through Cocoa fundamentals guide to get a good understanding of what's happening here. In any case, it is something you will have to do if you want to be an effective iOS developer.